# Jetty SPNEGO/SSO gives NPE. Expected cause krn5.ini?

Tags: cross-domain, single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego, gssapi

We're facing an issue where Jetty SPNEGO gives an NPE inside `SpnegoLoginService.login()`
The `gssContext.getSrcName()` call returns **null**.

The SPN is:   `HTTP/machine.dd.aa.net@EE.AA.NET`
Must there be a special setup in the KRB5.INI file when `dd.aa.net  !=   EE.AA.NET` ?

The only clue i found with Google is this warning message from some online source code:

```
if (gssContext.isEstablished()) {
    if (gssContext.getSrcName() == null) {
        log.warn("GSS Context accepted, but no context initiator recognized. Check your kerberos configuration and reverse DNS lookup configuration");
        return false;
    }
```

Our client-setup is

- Internet-explorer browser, setup for negotiate/spnego
- login using Windows SmartCard

Our server-setup is

- Java 8u45
- Jetty 9
- using org.eclipse.jetty.security.SpnegoLoginService

We used java kinit on the server to validate against the keytab and also against the DC. which went ok. Also the reverse DNS zones are working.

is there a possibility that the 'service request token' generated by the client browser (logged in with smartcard) doesn't supply the context initiator / client principle name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The nullpointer was gone when we went from *Java 1.8u45* to *Java 1.8u60*

Turns out the server side didn't check all tickets provided by the client, so didn't find the correct one.

Below the bug entry:
  *[[JDK-8078439]](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8078439) SPNEGO auth fails if client proposes MS krb5 OID*